# Können zwei verschiedene adverbiale Bestimmungen an der ersten Position eines Hauptsatzes gestellt werden?

Tags: adverbial, position

Als ich Deutsch anfing zu lernen, wurde mir erklärt, dass an der ersten Position eines Hauptsatzes nur ein "Objekt" gestellt werden könnte. Zum Beispiel, ein Subjekt, ein Dativ-Objekt, oder eine adverbiale Bestimmung, usw. Jedoch habe ich heute einen Satz gesehen, der etwa wie das Folgendes ist:

- Kurz nach dem Abitur hat sie geheiratet.

Es scheint mir, dass an der ersten Position dieses Satz es zwei Objekten gibt: ***kurz*** und ***nach dem Abitur***. Ich würde sagen, dass die beiden Objekte adverbiale Bestimmungen der Zeit sind. Der Grund für diese Behauptung ist, dass jeder von diesen Bestimmungen als unabhängige adverbial Bestimmung der Zeit arbeiten kann. Natürlich könnte es auch sein, dass die Kombination zwischen diesen eine andere unabhängige adverbiale Bestimmung der Zeit bilden könnte. Ich bin mir jedoch nicht sicher.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Kurz nach dem Abitur* ist eine einzige adverbiale Bestimmung der Zeit, nicht zwei.

Das ergibt sich daraus, dass *kurz* auf *nach dem Abitur* bezogen ist. Ohne *nach dem Abitur* hätte *kurz* einen völlig anderen Sinn:

> Kurz nach dem Abitur hat sie geheiratet.

> Kurz hat sie geheiratet.

Daher bildet *Kurz nach dem Abitur* einen einzigen Satzteil.

Es ist allerdings tatsächlich möglich, zwei nicht aufeinender bezogene adverbiale Bestimmungen zusammenzufassen und ins Vorfeld zu stellen:

> Gestern im Bahnhof hat es einen Vorfall gegeben.

Das ist ungewöhnlich, aber zulässig, obwohl es die Verbzweitstellung zu verletzen scheint. Adverbiale Bestimmung der Zeit und adverbiale Bestimmung des Ortes bilden hier zusammen einen einzigen Satzteil.

Das ist offenbar deswegen möglich, weil die beiden adverbialen Bestimmungen so ähneln, dass sie zusammengefasst werden können.

Dagegen wäre folgendes inkorrekt:

> *Gestern einen Vorfall hat es gegeben.

Objekt und adverbiale Bestimmung der Zeit können nicht zu einem einzigen Satzteil zusammengefasst und gemeinsam ins Vorfeld gestellt werden.